# IE Compatibility Issue. Images overflowing onto the line below

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, dreamweaver, compatibility

Im pretty new to Dreamweaver. Im having a problem. I have a website that works fine in Firefox,Chrome and Safari but the problem is with IE. For some reason the last image in my "div logos" section overflows onto the line below despite me setting it comfortably wide enough in the stylesheets to fit this and more images in.

Visit here to check it out: www.innexdesign.co.uk/dev

I'll paste the code below as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <meta name="keywords" content=" Innex Design, design, designers warrington, interior design warrington, cheshire, northwest, manchester, liverpool, pub designers,bar designers, architect, architects, carbon neutral, design manchester, designer in warrington, architect warrington" />
    <meta name="description" content=" From a house extension or housing estate, to commercial warehouses’, leisure centres and bars, Innex Design can help develop any idea into a practical, ethical, sustainable reality." />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<!-- #BeginEditable "doctitle" -->
<title>Innex Design</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />    
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

            $(".various1").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });
        });
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
    </script>   
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('images/architectureBLACK.png','images/interior-designBLACK.png','images/project-managementBLACK.png','images/cost-managementBLACK.png','images/PlanningBLACK.png','images/SurveyingBLACK.png','images/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png','images/landscape-architectureBLACK.png','images/Design-&amp;-BuildBLACK.png')">
<div id="header">
            <div id="headerimgs">
                <div id="headerimg1" class="headerimg"></div>
                <div id="headerimg2" class="headerimg"></div>

  </div>
    <div id="logo"> 
    <a href="index.html" target="_self"><img src="images/innexdesign_logo.jpg" width="143" height="206" alt="Innex Design Logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="social">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/InnexDesign" target="_new"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="41" height="40" alt="Innex Design on Twitter" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/innexdesignltd" target="_new"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="41" height="40" alt="Innex Design on Facebook" /></a>
         <a href="contactform.html" title="Request a Callback" target="_new"><img src="images/callback.png" alt="" width="77" height="40" /></a>
        <a href="contactform.html" title="Leave Your Details and Sign up to our News Letter" target="_new"><img src="images/Newsletter Image.png" alt="" width="77" height="40" /></a></div>
    </div><!-- end header -->

<div id="content">

    <div id="homeleft">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.html">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">DESIGNS</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>    
    <li class="last"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">CELEBRATING<br /><span style="font-size:22px">21</span><br />YEARS<br />1991-2012</p>

    </div>

  <div id="homeright">


<a class="various1" href="#architecture" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Architecture','','images/architectureBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/architecture.png" alt="Architecture" width="195" height="31" id="Architecture" style="padding:0px 20px;float:left;"/></a>
 <a class="various1" href="#idesign" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('interiordesign','','images/interior-designBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/interior-design.png" alt="Interior Design" width="195" height="31" id="interiordesign" style="padding:0px 0px 5px 20px; float:right;"/></a>
   <a class="various1" href="#pmanage" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Projman','','images/project-managementBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/project-management.png" alt="Project Managment" width="195" height="31" id="Projman" style="padding:20px 42px 5px 20px;float:left;"/></a>
<a class="various1" href="#planning" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Planning','','images/PlanningBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Planning.png" alt="Planning" width="195" height="31" id="Planning" style="padding:10px 12px 5px 0px;float:right;"/></a>

  <a class="various1" href="#energy" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Energy Assessment','','images/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/energy-assessments.png" alt="Energy Assessments" width="195" height="31" id="EnergyAssessment" style="padding:0px 42px 0px 20px;float:right;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#surveying" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Surveying','','images/SurveyingBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Surveying.png" alt="Surveying" width="195" height="31" id="Surveying" style="padding:10px;float:left;" /></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#cost" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('CostManagement','','images/cost-managementBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/cost-management.png" alt="Cost Management" width="195" height="31" id="CostManagement" style="padding:0px 12px 0px 20px; float:left;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#land" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('landscape','','images/landscape-architectureBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Landscape-Architecture.png" alt="Landscape Architecture" width="195" height="31" id="landscape" style="padding:20px 0px 0px 20px; float:right;" /></a>
    <div id="various1"> <a href="http://www.innexdevelopments.co.uk" target="_blank"  onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('DesignBuild','','images/Design-&amp;-BuildBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Design-&amp;-Build.png" alt="Design &amp; Build" width="195" height="31" id="DesignBuild" style="padding:10px 0 0 0px;float:left;"/></a>
    </div>


<div style="display:none"><div id="architecture">
        <img src="images/architecture.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Architecture" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">From a house extension or housing estate, to commercial warehouses’, leisure centres and bars, Innex Design can help develop any idea into a practical, ethical, sustainable reality.</p>  
    </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="idesign">
        <img src="images/interior-design.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Interior Design" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design’s Interior and brand development designers are experts in spatial design, brand development and awareness, signage and menu design all of which is complimented with the interior design package delivered.</p>   
        </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="pmanage">
        <img src="images/project-management.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Project Management" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Many of our architectural and interior design developments are project managed ensuring the brief and end aim is delivered on time and on budget. Only with project management can we ensure our clients that the specification and quality is to the highest standard.</p>
        </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="planning">
        <img src="images/Planning.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Planning" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design undertake all planning application submissions from residential, commercial, listed and conservation area consents, national park along with Display of Advertisement applications. We also work with planning consultants to add value for developers and lenders by assessing land and building use potential.</p>
        </div></div>

         <div style="display:none"><div id="surveying">
        <img src="images/Surveying.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Surveying" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design can provide a wide variety of surveys from measured & condition surveys of buildings, Topographical surveys, Structural surveys, Party Wall surveys, and provide assistance with Asbestos surveys, Land/Probate surveys, certification and many more.</p>
        </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="energy">
        <img src="images/energy-assessments.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Energy Assessments" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design can assist with providing full building services design & energy consultancy, and through one of our partners BREEAM assessment, Commercial EPC, Domestic EPC, Display energy certificates, New Build SAP or SBEM reports & Sustainability statements.</p>
        </div></div>

         <div style="display:none"><div id="cost">
        <img src="images/cost-management.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Cost Management" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design offer all clients a comprehensive service that removes the burden of day to day costs-related issues.</p>
        </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="land">
        <img src="images/Landscape-Architecture.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Landscape Architecture" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">We undertake all aspects of landscape architecture, from landscape master planning, conceptual design through to detailed planting schemes. We adopt a fresh approach to the design of each project where a high degree of design flair and innovation comes as standard. </p>
        </div></div>

         <div style="display:none"><div id="build">
        <img src="images/Design-&amp;-Build.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Design &amp; Build" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">In today’s industry and marketplace some clients prefer a one point of contact approach to projects, with this in mind we have developed a nationwide network of partnering contractors to enable clients to have the one point contact, whilst ensuring delivery of excellent quality and standards of workmanship.</p>
        </div></div>        

  </div>
</div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end wrapper -->


        <div id="logosother">
           <div class="logos">
        <a href="http://www.altiusva.com/ " target="_blank"><img src="images/altius-logo.jpg" width="107" height="50" alt="Altius Logo" /> </a> 
        <a href="http://www.chas.gov.uk " target="_blank"><img src="images/chas-logo.jpg" width="43" height="50" alt="Chas Logo" /></a>
         <a href="http://www.constructionline.co.uk/static/" target="_blank"><img src="images/Construction line.jpg" width="43" height="50" alt="Construction Line" longdesc="http://www.constructionline.co.uk/static/" /></a>   
         <a href="http://www.eurosafeuk.co.uk/ " target="_blank"><img src="images/Eurosafe.jpg" width="43" height="50" alt="Eurosafe" longdesc="http://www.eurosafeuk.co.uk/ " /></a> 
          <a href="http://committedtoequality.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="images/commitedtoequality.jpg" width="43" height="50" alt="Commited To Equality" longdesc="http://committedtoequality.co.uk" /></a>
         <a href="http://bii.bii.org/home" target="_blank"><img src="images/BII.jpg" alt="BII" width="43" height="50" longdesc="http://bii.bii.org/home" /></a></div>

        <div class="carbon"><a href="images/Carbon Managment Plan.pdf" target="_new"><img src="images/carbon-logo.jpg" width="149" height="85" alt="Carbon Neutral Logo" /></a></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p style="float:left">Copyright &copy; 2012 - Innex Design           </p>
    <p style="float: left">Privacy Policy</p>
    <p style="float: left"><a href="images/Sustainability Policy.pdf" target="_new">Sustainability Policy</a></p>
    <p style="float: left"><a href="images/Equal Ops Policy.pdf" target="_new">Equal Opportunities Policy</a></p>
<p style="float:right">Designed by <a href="http://www.swan-solutions.com" target="_blank" title="Swan Solutions"><img src="images/swan-solutions.jpg" alt="Swan Solutions" width="100" height="20" align="middle" /></a></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">



  var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25186334-1']);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



  (function() {

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();



</script>
</body>
</html>

@font-face {
   font-family: shruti;
   src: url(‘shruti.ttf’);
}

html, body, div, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color : #040404;
    background-image : url(images/bk.jpg);
    background-position : top;
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    font-family : shruti, Arial, Geneva;
    font-size : 90%;
    line-height:100%;
}
p {
    font-family : shruti, Arial, Geneva;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size : 100%;
    line-height:normal;
    padding: 5px;
}
h1 {
    font-size : 24px;
    padding-bottom:10px;    
}

h2 {
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
ul {
    list-style : none;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}
a:link {
    color : #000;
    text-decoration : none;
    color : #000;
}
a:active {
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
}
a:visited {
    font-style : italic;
    color : #00C;
}
a {
    outline: none;
}

a img {
    vertical-align: top;


}

a img.last {
    margin-right: 0;    
}

img {
    border : none;
}
#wrapper {
    width : 994px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    background-color : #e3d9b9;
}
#header {
    width : 994px;
    height : 483px;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
#page {
    width : 994px;
    position : relative;
    background-image : url(images/page_bk.jpg);
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : top;
    background-color : #b08f40;
}
#pageheader {
    width : 100%;
    height : 220px;
    position : relative;
    background-image : url(images/header_bk.png);
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-position : top;
}
#logo {
width : 143px;
height : 206px;
position : relative;
padding : 10px 10px 0 10px;
float : left;
}
#social {
float : left;
padding : 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
#content {
    width : 994px;
    min-height:200px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    padding : 0;
    background-image : url(images/homepage_bk.jpg);
    background-position : top;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-color : #b08f40;
    overflow:auto;
}
#logosother {
    height: 160px;
    width: 994px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #e3d9b9;
    background-image: url(images/top_footer.jpg);
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clear:both;

}
.logos {
    height:52px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:82px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9;
}
.carbon {
    height:90px;
    width: 159px;
    padding: 10px;
    float:right;
    margin-top:42px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9;
}
.googleplus {
    width:50px;
    height:32px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top:98px;
    margin-left:130px;  
    float:left;
}
.homelogos {
    height:52px;
    width: 974px;   
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:52px;
    background-color : #e3d9b9; 
}
#pagecontent {
    width : 100%;
    padding : 0;
    overflow : auto;
}
#left {
    width : 200px;
    float : left;
}
#homeleft {
    width : 200px;
    float : left;
}
.menu {
    margin-left : 10px;
    margin-top : 20px;
    margin-bottom : 10px;
}
.menu li {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #f9f5e7;
    border-top : 1px solid #a79c78;
    padding-bottom : 5px;
    padding-top : 5px;
    padding-left : 10px;
}
.menu li a {
    font-size : 18px;
    color : #000;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    font-weight : bold;
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
}
.menu li a:active {
    font-weight : bold;
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
}
.menu li a:visited {
    font-weight : bold;
    font-style : italic;
    color : #000;
}
.menu .first {
    border-top : none;
}
.menu .last {
    border-bottom : none;
}
#homeright {
    width : 700px;
    margin-left : 20px;
    float : left;
    padding-top : 20px;
    overflow:auto;

}
#right {
    width : 700px;
    margin-left : 20px;
    float : left;
    font-size : 14px;
    font-weight : normal;
    line-height : normal;
    padding-top : 20px;
}
#newright {
width : 730px;
min-height:300px;
float : left;
font-size : 14px;
font-weight : bold;
line-height : 135%;
margin-left : 30px;
padding-top : 20px;
}
.service_menu {
width : 190px;
float:left;
}
.service_menu li {
padding : 8px 0;
width:180px;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.service_menu li a {
font-size : 14px;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:hover {
font-weight : bold;
font-style : italic;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:active {
font-weight : bold;
font-style : italic;
color : #000;
}
.service_menu li a:visited {
color : #000;
}
.service_menu .first {
border-top : none;
}
.service_menu .last {
border-bottom : none;
}
.serv {
    min-height:300px;
}
.des3 {
float : left;
width : 300px;
margin-left:20px;
}
.desimg3 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}
#footer {
    width : 984px;
    height : 40px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    font-size : 12px;
    padding : 5px;
    clear : both;
    background-image : url(images/footer_bk.jpg);
    background-repeat : repeat-x;
    color: #000;
}

.msg_list {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 670px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-image : url(images/expand_bk.png);
background-repeat : repeat-x;
height : 29px;
line-height : 29px;
color : #000;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 12px;
padding-left : 10px;
}
.msg_head :hover {
padding : 5px 10px;
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-color : #fff;
color : #fff;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 16px;
}
.msg_body {
overflow : auto;
padding : 10px 10px;
}
.msg_body p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
}
.des {
float : left;
width : 300px;
padding-right:10px;
}
.desimg {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}

.msg_list1 {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 300px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head1 {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
height : 31px;
}
.msg_head1 :hover {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
}
.msg_body1 {
overflow : auto;
padding : 0 10px;
}
.msg_body1 p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
}
.des1 {
float : left;
width : 300px;
margin-right : 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin-top:10px;
}

.desimg1 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}

.newdes {
float : left;
width : 340px;
margin-right : 10px;
}
.msg_list2 {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 360px;
float : left;
}
.msg_head2 {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
background-image : url(images/expand_bk.png);
background-repeat : repeat-x;
height : 31px;
line-height : 31px;
color : #000;
margin : 1px;
font-size : 12px;
padding-left : 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
.msg_head2 :hover {
cursor : pointer;
position : relative;
margin : 1px;
}
.msg_body2 {
overflow : auto;
padding : 0 10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.msg_body2 p {
font-size : 12px;
line-height : 150%;
font-weight : normal;
padding:0px;
}
.newdes2 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.desimg2 {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}


.servintro {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 700px;
overflow : auto;
}
.servintrotext {
float : left;
width : 270px;
padding : 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
.servintroimg {
float : left;
width : 340px;
}
#slider {
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
}
#slider ul, #slider li {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
list-style : none;
}
#slider li {
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
overflow : hidden;
}
.headerimg {
background-position : center top;
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 994px;
height : 483px;
position : absolute;
}
.testimonial {
border : 1px solid #000;
padding : 10px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-top : 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
.office {
border : 1px solid #000;
padding : 10px;
margin-bottom : 10px;
margin-top : 10px;
width:100%;
height:265px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
* {
padding : 0;
}
#TB_window {
font : 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color : #333333;
}
#TB_secondLine {
font : 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:link {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:visited {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:hover {
color : #000;
}
#TB_window a:active {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_window a:focus {
color : #666666;
}
#TB_overlay {
position : fixed;
z-index : 100;
top : 0;
left : 0;
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
}
.TB_overlayMacFFBGHack {
background : url(macFFBgHack.png) repeat;
}
.TB_overlayBG {
background-color : #000;
}
* html #TB_overlay {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_window {
position : fixed;
background : #ffffff;
z-index : 102;
color : #000000;
display : none;
border : 4px solid #525252;
text-align : left;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
}
* html #TB_window {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_window img#TB_Image {
display : block;
margin : 15px 0 0 15px;
border-right : 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom : 1px solid #ccc;
border-top : 1px solid #666;
border-left : 1px solid #666;
}
#TB_caption {
height : 25px;
padding : 7px 30px 10px 25px;
float : left;
}
#TB_closeWindow {
height : 25px;
padding : 11px 25px 10px 0;
float : right;
}
#TB_closeAjaxWindow {
padding : 7px 10px 5px 0;
margin-bottom : 1px;
text-align : right;
float : right;
}
#TB_ajaxWindowTitle {
float : left;
padding : 7px 0 5px 10px;
margin-bottom : 1px;
}
#TB_title {
background-color : #e8e8e8;
height : 27px;
}
#TB_ajaxContent {
clear : both;
padding : 2px 15px 15px 15px;
overflow : auto;
text-align : left;
line-height : 1.4em;
}
#TB_ajaxContent.TB_modal {
padding : 15px;
}
#TB_ajaxContent p {
padding : 5px 0 5px 0;
}
#TB_load {
position : fixed;
display : none;
height : 13px;
width : 208px;
z-index : 103;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
margin : -6px 0 0 -104px;
}
* html #TB_load {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_HideSelect {
z-index : 99;
position : fixed;
top : 0;
left : 0;
background-color : #fff;
border : none;
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
}
* html #TB_HideSelect {
position : absolute;
}
#TB_iframeContent {
clear : both;
border : none;
margin-bottom : -1px;
margin-top : 1px;
}
hr {
    border: none;
    height: 1px; line-height: 1px;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.designimage {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    border:solid 2px #000;  
}
.designlogo {
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left; 
}
.mapleft {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}
.mapcenter {
    float:left;
    width:260px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.mapright {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
}
```

Comment: Its doing it in all IE browsers. 6.0,7.0.8.0,9. By the way he best example of eeing this is www.innexdesign.co.uk/dev/educational.html...The other pages i have tried resizing the images smaller but i dont like the look and feel of using that method so if you wan to see what i mean please see www.innexdesign.co.uk/dev/educational.html....Thanks very much for any help

Comment: The 'all-ie-only.css' that you're using is setting the div.logos to width:350px. If you set it to 400px like in the normal css, it should display fine. Or just set it to width:auto to be safe. It should work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a css file that is name all-ie-only.css.

```
.logo { width: 350px; } // change it to 400px
.logo { width: 400px; } // it is the same width in style.css line 131
```

if you do that you dont need to change it in all-ie-only.css. just delete the width.

Comment: Your welcome :) For better practice about "Conditional Comments", i suggest you to visit this [link](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments).

Comment: It now work perfectly except for one issue: [link]www.innexdesign.co.uk/dev/services.html[/link]                                             The whole site now works perfectly in IE but in Firefox and Chrome when you hover over "designs for drinking" down through "designs for eating", "designs for sleeping" etc the page wobbles slightly pushin the logo and footer divs down on the page. If you click in designs for drinking and hover through the bars or designs for eating and hover over the restaurants the same ting happens in Chrome and to a lesser extent Firefox. Any idea???

Comment: try this if you want to 
`#right { width: 750px;  }
.service_menu {  width: 210px;}
.service_menu li { remove the width line }
.slider { float: right; }`